# Can't access folder after ssh

Tags: unix, ssh

I ssh on the root of hosting site.

When I `cd WORDPRESS`, I get no such file or directory.

I tried `sudo -i` but same result.

When I `ls -al`, I can see the directory:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1299 Mar  6 17:15 WORDPRESS
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1299 Mar  6 17:15 WORDPRESS
```

is not a directory but a regular file. Directories have `d` as the first char in this listing.

Answer (score 1):

WORDPRESS in that listing is not a directory. Directories have a 'd' preceding the file permissions on the left hand side.